# Suppose that $f'$ is a bounded derivative of a function $f$ over $[a,b]$. Does $f'$ always achieve minimum and maximum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I believe that there exits some function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that its derivative $f'$ is bounded but f' doesn't attain its minimum( or maximum) in $[a,b]$

By Darboux's theorem, we can infer that $f([a,b])$ is also an interval, say $J$. If it is an open interval, then $f$ is the example we want.

Comment: If it has derivative, then it's continuous. If it's continuous, then it attains it's minimum and maximum. I'm assuming you mean $f'$ in the whole interval $[a, b]$

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin of couse

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin, your use of “it” is totally ambiguous. No one said that $f’$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x) = (1-x)x^2 \sin\frac1x$, on the interval $[0,1]$ so that $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
(2x-3x^2)\sin\frac1x-(1-x){\cos \frac1x}&x>0\\
0 &x=0
\end{cases}
$$
As $x\to 0^+$, $f'(x)$ oscillates with minima and maxima approaching, but never reaching, $\pm1$.

See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5uaxygx8ep. Here is a graph of $f'$:

[image]